# Tensorflow: Reinforcement learning with variable character level text input?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, reinforcement-learning

Taking into consideration a reinforcement learning context whereby the Tensorflow agent will take a "step" in the environment for each observation that is received.
[image]

How would one most effectively accommodate an observation of variable lengths, for instance when an observation exceeds a 1024 placeholder limit **(i.e. 10000 char long Wikipedia article)** noting that placeholders are immutable and can't be dynamically changed during computation:

```
self.obs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,1024), name='obs')
```

**I am familiar with the padding method** whereby a maximum line length is specified and the chars not occupied are filled in with a placeholder. However, this method seems ineffective when processing inputs with varying lengths between 100 chars and 10000 chars, whereby the shape of the placeholder would have to be `(None, 10000)` even when processing inputs that are only 100 chars in length effectively using 9900 placeholder chars and a large **EXPENSIVE** amount of memory and computation that is effectively useless, compounded even more so in a reinforcement learning context whereby millions of steps are being taken in order to learn an effective policy.

**I'm aware of the word embedding method.**

[image]

However, there are a multitude of issues with this method which include but are not limited to: Lack of detail and by extension performance, lack of punctuation understanding and other character and logic representations as in a mathematical formula.etc

How could one effectively structure an input flow whereby a varying input size can effectively be consumed by a Tensorflow agent in a manner that avoids the aforementioned problems?